Why is Wagenknecht's (new) party seen as a more acceptable governance partner than Die Linke that it split from?
I could be mistaken, in which case please write a frame-challenging answer, but my impression after reading a couple of pieces (e.g.) about Wagenknecht's new party (BSW) and its level of success in the Eastern state elections is that it is considered by the CDU a more acceptable coalition partner than Die Linke (that BSW essentially split from, as I understand). So, why is that the BSW is considered more acceptable?
(FWTW, one academic piece finds that Wagenecht was the Linke "MP with the highest share of populist communication" and that that in particular has translated into BSW's platform as its "anti-elitism resembles classic left-wing populist rhetoric". But I'm not sure how that relates to anything other than electoral success.)

I wonder where exactly CDU says that? It's not more acceptable I think, it's just that there is no other option if you don't want to include the very right AFD and it seems that the other parties don't want that. I guess BSW didn't become more mainstream than Die Linke but requirements were lowered in order to avoid AFD. Also it's on a federal level in Eastern Germany.

If a coalition of CDU and BSW happens, and it's not sure yet, there will be quite some stretching of both parties positions necessary. It won't be a match made in heaven. The real question is probably why the CDU prefers BSW to AFD and I think it's clear why: AFD is much more a competitor for CDU. They don't want to promote their direct competitor.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution The AFD aren't a democratic, conservative competitor to the CDU, but in particular those parties in Sachsen and Thüringen are listed by the Verfassungsschutz (institution tasked with the protection of the constitution) as "gesichert rechtsextrem" so beyond reasonable doubt right wing extremist. So while the CDU is probably THE single most established party in Germany (together with the SPD though that one is declining quite hard), the AFD, in particular in those states, is not even in accord with the values of the constitution.

@haxor789 Be that as it may, in many other questions CDU and AFD are relatively close in my eyes, including but not limited to immigration or how not to protect the environment, or opposition to the left. Maybe they even share the same voter segment. And the SPD, which you see declining hard, is currently providing the chancellor. Germany in 2024 is very heterogeneous.

From Germany. If you remove Sahra from Die Linke, only very little remains. Maybe Gregor Gysi, but somehow I have seen him lesser active recently, maybe due to his age. He is clearly above an acceptable age of a chancellor. Their shared success was seen really well - their politics was absolutely not what one can except from a post-communist party. Their split must had a reason, and I think, it has probably killed the party. Now there is die Linke, without any face, and there is Sahra, without a party. Only the AfD has profited from this split, which is a generally disliked party here.

Btw, AfD is disliked but it is actually only a psychological phenomenon. In the today Germany, all the parties want to show that they are not nazi. Thus, they find one, they call them nazi, and then they close with them out any cooperation. On this way, they all can show that they are not nazi. If the AfD would not exist, they would need to fulfill this important role with another party, maybe with one of them, what no one wants. This is why AfD, while it is nazi-like, unconstituonal, anti-democratic, usw., it is actually never forcibly forbidden, what is the law for really nazi parties.

It is actually some sort of voodoo magic. You pull the nazi puppet out of the desk, and then you spike it with needles. Voodoo magic thinks that it is a way to harm the real nazis. In your political life, it is your way to show, that you are not nazi.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Not be it as it may. The CDU might be corrupt and willing to throw the environment under the bus when it comes to companies complaining. Though to be fair in recent years even the Greeen party has been willing to do that, so maybe it's not just corruption but a real problem. But that's an entirely different level than the AfD who's still ideologically convinced that climate change isn't real. Or the CDU playing the tough guys on immigration knowing that according to Dublin II Germany doesn't need to take anyone compared to expatriating citizens and racist nationalism

@NoDataDumpNoContribution 2/ Basically the CDU is the establishment, while pretending to be the alternative to the other establishment (social democracy), while the AfD actually WANTS to do all this crazy bullshit. Sure there have always been those kinds of lunatics in the CDU as well, but they had been a minority and supported the larger party, now they have a standalone party and a sizable portion of the electorate DESPITE being openly beyond the democratic consensus. While the leftist parties struggle because a lot of crises outside of their control are attributed to their responsibility.

@GraySheep Die Linke has famously tried to be the party without face since their inception. Their billboards at first literally where walls of text with no faces. They maybe naively seriously thought voters would care about issues rather than people. So Wagenknecht was already an outlier, but I afaik during the entire time she made it most about herself and less about the party or even politics. And in recent years she attempted a querfront where as a leftist politician she went with dipped into right culture war rhetoric. So the split was more or less a matter of time.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The CDU has pretty much hailed itself as the most right wing party in the democratic spectrum. The FDP might have challenged them on the economic angle of that, but social conservatism was kind of their domain. There were parties like the NPD, die Rechte, Republikaner, 3. Weg and various other far right, extremist or outright fascist parties, but they rarely caught relevant traction to get into parliaments and were pretty unanimously seen as outside of the democratic spectrum.
While on the other side of the spectrum you had the SPD, die Grünen and die Linke who had founded itself from a merger of PDS (post-SED (east German ruling party) and the WASG (essentially people who thought the SPD had moved to much to the right).
So long story short within the democratic spectrum CDU and die Linke are pretty much the edge cases, the CDU even questioned whether die Linke is within the democratic spectrum (but lost on that one). And as ccprog has mentioned they have even made commitments not to cooperate with either die Linke or the AfD. The latter, unlike Die Linke, has not just been under surveillance for their anti-constitutional goals, but in the respective states in questions has been confirmed as far right extremist.
So a coalition of CDU and AfD is basically off limits and would seriously put the democratic system in Germany at risk. However their preferred partner FDP didn't even make it into parliament. The Grand coalition of the formerly biggest parties CDU and SPD also has problems with the SPD having lost by a lot. The Green party is already not their preferred option but they also not or barely made it into parliament and "die Linke" as said was declared to be off limits for them.
Now as the far right extremist AfD scored high, to avoid them getting anywhere near government there needs to be a coalition of multiple parties and the BSW with double digit numbers is hardly to be avoided in that. Now the BSWs program is largely unknown, the name is geared towards one person who's a real mixed bag going from Stalin apologist to fan of west german conservatism, pretty populist, "pro-Russian", socially conservative, but pretending to be economically left wing. And that the CDU doesn't have a commitment not to cooperate with that is likely mostly because they are too new for that.
So yeah it's not as if that party is seen as more acceptable, it's more or less that the CDU is running out of acceptable options.

"but pretending to be economically left wing." Who's to say that they aren't? A lot of progressive people underestimate the extent to which "redistribution and nationalization, but only for us" can appeal to people belonging to large enough social groups to be part of "us." There's at least one relatively prolific person on this site who would pretty much fit the description of "hard left pro-authoritarian with disdain for identity-based social justice to outright bigotry," and it's a pretty strong profile in some countries (like Russia).

In another country, this is also helps understand where Trump's personal philosophy differs from his traditionalist predecessors. He's still a right-wing person who mainly gives the fiscal conservatives free reign, but he doesn't personally understand their disdain for social welfare, and so his rhetoric in that regard, coupled with more explicit racism and other bigotry, found a wider audience among his base.

@Obie2.0 The problem is that this entire dichotomy of pretending that the economic and culturual frame could be separated and would be viable on their own doesn't work. The leftist ideal is a unified society, without hierarchies that cooperates towards individual and collective growth. The right wing ideal is to be the leader or part of that person's peer group, which tells an underclass what to do. And they compete for that spot or the best places in that team. Whether the battleground is politics, nationalism, racism, sexism, economics, ... hardly matters the goal is to subjugate and rule.

@Obie2.0 2/ Of course it's appealing if you address a disenfranchised underclass with "Do you want to be better off? Look over there, these people are between you and a live full of luxury. What are you waiting for". That's called "populism" and both leftists and rightists are able to do that, the problem is the outcome of that is almost always distinctly right wing. Because you effectively educate people to think of their peers as inferior and to throw them under the bus and if that is successful, well what do you think they will go on doing?

@Obie2.0 3/ And if you don't believe me, you might realize that your proposal in the first comment might be called "national socialism" (might ring a bell). And examples of that such as Hitler's Germany or Stalininist "socialism in one country" have almost exclusively taken a hard turn to the far right and I'm not speaking about fiscal conservatism and deficite spending which isn't even a dividing line between politics... but about whether you harvest your wealth from cooperation or exploitation of others.

@Obie2.0 4/ Though to be fair actually people don't address a disenfranchised underclass like that, but the middle class and get them accustomed to look at the actual underclass with contempt until it's a binary of either be part of the team (even if it's at the lowest level) or be part of "the other" and suffer. Also yeah there is an uneasy alliance between groups willing to throw people under the bus. Like who already doesn't care about the poor and isn't effected by racism and bigotry is more likely to accept that if they think it aids them.

@Obie2.0 5/ The problem is, that this breaks societies apart. Democracy relies on equality of citizens, in political power, before the law and so on. While if you can remove your opposition from society and reducing their political influence by other means and people turning a blind eye to that because they think they can profit from that as well. Then you're up for a reign of terror. And while 20th century was still optimistic that would remind people how productive cooperation was, awfulness unfortunately proved surprisingly stable.

@Obie2.0 6/6 Also, people attribute too much ideology to authoritarianism. Like exessive violence covers a lack of effective control. Secrecy and individualization outside of controlled collectivization hinders organized resistance. Cults and teams make it easier to purge opposition -> "part of the enemy team. You don't agree? Also part of the enemy team!". Taking control of welfare also makes people reliant on the system of oppression. Which doesn't mean that welfare is authoritarian, if you cut it you don't remove the problem you likely only push people towards alternatives like gangs...

Sorry, this feels a lot like "no true Scotsman" to me. The assertion of Stalinism as "far right" in particular.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The argument is mostly formal: The CDU has a "Unvereinbarkeitsbeschluss" (formal resolution of incommensurateness) with Die Linke, which means that any form of cooperation with them is excluded. Such a resolution does not exist in regard to BSW.
A party publication explains:

Wie sieht die Beschlusslage der CDU Deutschlands aus?
Die CDU Deutschlands hat hierzu eine klare Beschlusslage: Keine Zusammenarbeit mit der Linkspartei. Keine Zusammenarbeit mit der Alternativen für Deutschland.
So haben wir es auf dem 31. Parteitag der CDU Deutschlands am 8. Dezember 2018 in Hamburg beschlossen:
„Die CDU Deutschlands lehnt Koalitionen und ähnliche Formen der
Zusammenarbeit sowohl mit der Linkspartei als auch mit der Alternative für
Deutschland ab.“
Beschlüsse C76, C101, C164 und C179


What is the position of the CDU in Germany?
The CDU in Germany has a clear decision on this: no co-operation with the Left Party. No co-operation with the Alternative for Germany.
This is what we decided at the 31st party conference of the CDU Germany on 8 December 2018 in Hamburg:
‘The CDU of Germany rejects coalitions and similar forms of cooperation with both the Left Party and the Alternative for Germany.’
Resolutions C76, C101, C164 and C179

The paper contains further explanations of their position, including details on the 2020 election of the Minister President of Thuringia.

What might the CDU want with it? Percents are not enough in his favor, not even on the West. A cooperation does not mean that they love each other, or accept each other, it means only that they have a contract with each other. How could they collect enough vote with a very limited first place and only on the West? Or would they join with the blues or the greens?
